# Drawbacks of using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, frontend

I have heard lots and lots of good things for jQuery but what are some of the drawbacks with current version of jQuery and what features you want in next release of jQuery ?

Comment: It only gets better with each version - just my 2 cents - the only drawback I could see to using it would be filesize perhaps, but nowdays, most images you find are larger in filesize than the minified jQuery library. It's a blessing to cross-browser development.

Comment: it works on internet explorer... major drawback if you ask me :)

Comment: @alex: Easily fixed. Check for IE and, if found, don't load jQuery. ;p

Answer (score 15, accepted):

A big, big drawback is its abstraction hides the "ugly parts" of JavaScript, therefore making learning JS a lot more difficult. This is a problem that plagues the JS community. What ends up happening is you have designers/developers that can do simple rollovers and slideshows, but run into big problems once real DOM manipulation comes into play.

Another drawback is not just size, but how amorphous jQuery really is. With each new browser (most notably Internet Explorer), a fair amount of work is being done behind the scenes to expand the codebase. This was most evident with IE8, in which a fair amount of jQuery had to be re-written to at least comply with the newest version of IE. The result is you have a giant collection of methods and properties (over 200KB since about jQuery 1.5). Even with a wide array of options to compress/cache the files, you're still going to experience a decent amount of load time (a few seconds on a good connection).

One of those options is through Google's Content Distribution Network (CDN). It can cache jQuery for you and lead to quicker load times. However, you're now relying on two sources to operate flawlessly. Recently, Google flubbed one of the new (>= 1.5) versions of jQuery. This led to some incompatibilities for a few hours and posed problems for jQueryUI and various plugins. As I said earlier, you're relying on two sources to always work. Saving your own localized version can mitigate this risk.

I think given proper planning and usage, it can be a boon to most projects. However, I do emphasize that proper planning needs to be used. First ask yourself (or your team) if flashy fades and pseudo-tweens are really required for your project. These are the types of things that should be added last in order to maximize efficiency.

Those are the problems I have on my mind right now. Hopefully, this will be of some aid to you in the future.

Comment: Haha this reminds me of a talk we had earlier @Matt McDonald +1 :)

Comment: Care to explain what "real DOM manipulation" would be... in terms of what you can do that would be better accomplished without jQuery??

Comment: @philwinkle, it was more of an observation related to DOM theory. If someone lacks the understanding of the DOM, manipulation can become troublesome. No library can give you the knowledge to know how to use the DOM. That has to be learned through time and effort.

Comment: One technique I've seen is to serve your own copy of jQuery, and put a timestamp in the filename (e.g. "jQuery_20110317.min.js") and tell your web server to set the cache expiration time for that file to a year.  Then your users only load it once per year at most, unless you post a new version and change the filename. The downside is you have to change the filename in every <script> tag it's used in.

Comment: "A big, big drawback is its abstraction hides the "ugly parts" of JavaScript" <-- which is also the major benefit for using it.

Answer (score 3):

For me, any drawbacks with jQuery would not be about what features it's missing, but what *unnecessary features it includes*.

- jQuery seems to include so many different ways of doing the same thing.  There are lots of little methods that are shortcuts to the same functionality in other methods.

  It means that the documentation seems needlessly complex in places and it's hard to remember every different way of doing the same thing.  It can make it harder to understand other people's code if they use different ways of doing the same thing.
- The codebase just keeps growing.  Less than 30Kb gzipped and minified is still impressive, but it's reaching the size where it's larger than any CSS file or header image I ever had to load.  It takes a "monolithic kernel" sort of approach to a Javascript library, which is probably a large factor in its success - it includes everything you'd want in one place rather than making it more modular.

It's not a huge complaint.  jQuery is very powerful and robust.  But I brought this up because the original question seems to assume that jQuery could only be improved by adding more features to it.  I disagree - jQuery has reached a maturity level where lack of features is no longer one of its major drawbacks.

Comment: I never thought of any unnecessary features already present in jQuery, thanks for pointing me in that direction.

Comment: There are never different ways to order arguments, some of them are just optional and you will often see options hashes. IMO that is the only sane way of doing things, the alternative tends to be fairly unreadable code, even if the documentation becomes more straight forward.

Comment: I struggled with my choice of words I think.  When I said different ways to order arguments I meant that many methods could be given different combinations of arguments to achieve the same thing, or sometimes even adding arguments would distinctly change behaviour.  Such as, including an "options" object vs listing the same options as separate arguments, or adding an extra argument to make the method change from a getter to a setter.

Answer (score 3):

Compared to what? In what context? In and of itself, it's hard to say it has any drawbacks.

But in certain situations, there are some drawbacks:

- it's big. The jQuery library is a hit on your server and something the end-user has to download. Minimizing, CDN'ing, Caching, etc all help minimize it, but if you're are looking for super-light-weight JS solution, writing it from scratch will likely get you a small file size.
- a lot of the DOM CSS manipulation it does isn't necessarily optimized from an accessibility POV. It's getting better...especially all the ARIA stuff the filament group is doing
- not everyone is a fan of jQuery UI. It's good, for sure. But also a bit heavy handed, IMHO.
- it can be a bit confusing if you don't understand some of the basics of JS. It's good to understand what jQuery is doing behind the scenes at times.

But, honestly, you have to dig to really complain about it. IMHO, jQuery + StackOverflow has made Web Development fun again. ;o)

Answer (score 2):

If the question is "Should I use a library for javascript?" The answer is an unequivocal yes. The worst thing about javascript is the differing implementations, and using a js library will dramatically mitigate that problem. There hasn't been much professional javascript work done without using some sort of library since around 2005 or so when prototype hit.

If the question is more "What are the relative strengths of JQuery?", here are some points

- It is only a dom abstraction library. If you need to do more then small animations or style changes, jquery by itself is not enough.
- That being said, that is all most people want to do, which is a big part of why it is so popular. The problem with extreme popularity is people who are not serious javascript developers tend to think javascript == jquery, which it really isn't.
- Basically, if you are adding some trivial behavior to a page, jquery is fantastic. If you are building a "RIA" webapp, you want to look more at dojo (or even sproutcore, depending on how far you want to go). If you are somewhere in the middle, MooTool will do everything you need.
- If you are the type of person that would rather build their own toolset rather then go for a "Everything and the kitchen sink" type framework, jquery + underscore + backbone will take you pretty far.

Comment: It's more than 'just' a dom abstraction library for 'small trivial behaviors'. Certainly Dojo or ExtJS or other libraries may be better suited for a particular project, but jQuery is much more than just making animations.

Comment: @DA: Ok, it is dom library with a few utility methods thrown in, where it is comprehensive and really shines is in dom manipulation. Ext is a a full GUI toolkit, but it isn't a comprehensive library either. Things like Dojo and sproutcore are full platforms that cover everything you need to write a javascript _application_. JQuery is useful for sites, or for webapps where the majority of the work is done server side.

Comment: rebecca murphy did a great job talking about this here http://blog.rebeccamurphey.com/on-jquery-large-applications (although backbone didnt exist when she wrote it). Personally, I prefer a "hodgepodge of tools" when I can get away with it rather then massive frameworks. But even though I would rather tie all the pieces together that I need, I think it would be a lie to say that it is in any way more productive to wire all that stuff together then use something appropriate for the problem in the first place.

Comment: That's a good blog post. And I agree. That said, I'd say jQuery, in the enterprise, 75% of the time, is going to be an improvement over what is currently there (often a mish-mash of antiquated active-x controls, bloated paid-for JS components, way too much being handled server-side, Flash, browser-centric code, etc.). I've been a part of projects where Dojo was spec'd before realizing a) all they really needed was some nice UI improvements and b) they couldn't find anyone that had used it. ;)

Answer (score 1):

I think it depends on the level of JavaScript expertise we're talking about. If we're talking from the beginner through intermediate perspective, the drawback is that it can be a crutch preventing developers from honing their native JS skills (on the other hand, it can also be a bridge INTO JS development - it certainly has been for me).

Once you become interested in working more in pure JS, the main drawback is that it is DOM-centric. As your programming becomes more data-focused, the bias towards the DOM can sometimes get in the way.

It can also get a bit tricky to keep all your code organized as your code gets larger.

I think what I would most like to see going forward is some sort of dependency management - eg, let my scripts auto-load, or not, any needed plugins and components.

Having said all that, I am definitely a fan of jQuery and it is my JS library of choice. I find the strengths far outweigh the weaknesses, and that it is improving all the time.

Comment: Have you looked at backbone? IMO for a good js dev, jquery + backbone + underscore + handlebars can be a really nice "stack" for larger scale work.

Comment: I recently discovered underscore, which is really useful. Have heard of, but not explored, backbone - will definitely check out that and handlebars!

Answer (score 0):

The main drawback(other than the fact that it abstracts some key concepts of javascript) is the fact that is bundles everything, thus the library is going to be inherently large.

Large javascript files = more load time.

Also don't get me wrong, I love jQuery ... I'm just showing you the other side of the story :)